# Interactive PositionalAudio component in react-three-fiber drei

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

Im making a 3D website and just tried to place audio using PositionalAudio by using react-three-fiber drei. But it's not working due to google new autoplay policy. So I needed to play my website music using the PositionalAudio component and with a play/stop button, which plays and stops the music with the user's command. So is there any way to do an interactive audio player by using the PositionalAudio component in react-three-fiber drei?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set some trigger for it. I fixed mine by conditionally rendering it with state.

```
<Suspense>
    <mesh position={[0, 0, 0]}>
      <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color="red" />
      {musicZoom && (
        <PositionalAudio autoplay loop = {false} url="/discoSite.mp3" distance={3} />
      )}
    </mesh>
  </Suspense>
```